# Did KeePassX ever have an audit funding?

Tags: audit

Did KeePassX ever had an Audit Funding like ex.: TrueCrypt? Or any other password manager?

Comment: If you're concerned about the security of the database file itself, encrypting *it* with another program like gpg/pgp or Truecrypt/LUKS/etc could only help. Don't worry much about KeePass protecting itself from snooping apps or spyware, if you have those you're already boned

Comment: Apparently the EU is doing one ... [KeePass Password Manager is getting a code audit](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/22/keepass-password-manager-icode-audit/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  [news page](https://www.keepassx.org/news/) from [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/) lists several new versions, but there is no text about a funding campaign. Also if you search the web, you won't find anything. So I assume there was no funding campaign so far.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the other password managers part of the question -- specifically [KeePass](https://keepass.info/).

As Tyler Jordan writes in [his comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108659/did-keepassx-ever-have-an-audit-funding#comment277804_108659) there is a code audit of KeePass password manager under [EU-FOSSA](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/collection/eu-fossa) project.

Review report is available [here](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/page/project-deliveries) (look for *Deliverable WP6-01: Code review*) or use [direct link](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/inline-files/DLV%20WP6%20-01-%20KeePass%20Code%20Review%20Results%20Report_published.pdf) to the PDF version.

Comment: KeePass and KeePassX are two different programs. Though they share the same password database format, not all conclusions from KeePass audit can be used to infer the same for KeePassX. Weak cryptography implementations could potentially weaken the actual encryption even when the encryption technique itself are capable of strong security in another implementation.

Comment: @LieRyan You are right. I know there is a difference between KeePass and KeePassX. I posted this as an answer to the _Or any other password manager?_ part of the question. I will clarify that in the answer. Please let me know if you think this answer is inappropriate and I will delete it. (I came across this question while looking for some audited password manager and thought link to the EU-FOSSA might be helpful for others)